# Calling Posts from Specified Cat

Tags: query-posts, loop

The following is not working to call posts from a specific category and only grab the number of posts selected.

I'm using more than one loop on a page as I am using this to create a "featured content" section on my homepage.

```
    <?php
    ('cat=111&posts_per_page=1');
    if (have_posts())
    ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually running any queries. Need to run **wp_query()**, **query_posts()** or **get_posts()**. All are covered in great detail within the codex. Though you already have your parameters listed up ;)